# Need to login to ipb board with php and curl

Tags: curl, ipb

I'm trying to login to IP board with CURL and PHP. This is the code that I'm using. Anyone have an idea?

```
<?php

    $url=stream_get_contents(fopen('https://invisioncommunity.com/login/', "rb"));

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }

    $csrf_key = get_string_between($url, '" value="', '">');

    $path = "/root/ctemp";

    $postinfo = "csrfKey=".$csrf_key."&auth=____USERNAME_______&password=___PASSWORD____&remember_me=1&_processLogin=usernamepassword&_processLogin=usernamepassword";
    $cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    //set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://invisioncommunity.com/login/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
    curl_exec($ch);

    //page with the content I want to grab
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://invisioncommunity.com/discover/unread/");

    //do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $html;

    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, your csrf token is tied to a cookie session given to the stream_get_contents request, without that cookie, your csrf token is worthless, and you never extract the cookie from stream_get_contents (and i don't think stream_get_contents even support doing that), rewrite it with the curl_ api, and make sure curl's cookie system is enabled (eg, set CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to emptystring, that will enable libcurl's cookie handling system). also your csrf extraction code is unreliable, it doesn't decode html entities (for example, if the csrf token contains an `&`, it will be html-encoded as `&amp;`, but your code does not translate `&amp;` back to `&`. ), use a proper HTML parser instead, like DOMDocument. also you don't urlencode csrf_key, so again it may be corrupted if it contains special characters (like an @, more on that later). use urlencode() or http_build_query() to properly urlencode the csrf key, and your username, and your password, because you're not urlencoding those either. did you know that the `@` in your email must be encoded to `%40` ? i bet, when you hardcode your login email, you just write `foo@gmail.com`, you don't write `foo%40gmail.com`, so you'll have to urlencode that too.

try this, using http_build_query to encode the post data, and DOMDocument to parse out the csrf token:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '',
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://invisioncommunity.com/login/' 
) );
$html = curl_exec ( $ch );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://invisioncommunity.com/login/',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'csrfKey' => $xp->query ( '//input[@name="csrfKey"]' )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "value" ),
                'auth' => '____USERNAME_______',
                'password' => '___PASSWORD____',
                'remember_me' => 1,
                '_processLogin' => 'usernamepassword' 

        ) ) 
) );
$html = curl_exec ( $ch );
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thnx, Man ur great , without ur help i can't do it... it works